# Difference in using __icontains and lowercasing the query?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-queryset

Is there any difference in performance if I lower case the query before going to use `__contains` or directly using `__icontains`. In code:

**This**

```
def search(request):
    query = (request.GET.get("q")).lower()
    if query:
        users = User.objects.filter(location__contains=query)
```

**VS**

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        users = User.objects.filter(location__icontains=query)
```

I lowercased the `location` while inserting it into database. And, query is the query which can be in any cases.

Feel free to ask!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, the ***case-insensitive*** search (or the `LIKE` operation) is carried out by converting the LHS and RHS into same cases, either to lower case or to upper case.

Something like this,

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE UPPER(YourColumn) = UPPER('VALUE')
```

If you are sure that your DB column `location` only contains lowercase characters, **the first option is better**.

**Note:** You may not see any performance difference in small databases(10k entries), but you will see it on bigger DBs.

Comment: Can you give me any reference for better search performance. What I mean is if I search ```kerla``` this will give no result. I want it to know that the ```kerala``` or ask if you mean ```kerala```. I used that location for example, to made it easier.

Comment: Now you are asking about ***Fuzzy search***, and I don't think popular DBs are not equipped with that feature yet.